# HABTM relationship checkboxes with an option to add more

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a `Company` and a `Product` model with `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship.

```
# app/models/company.rb

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end


# app/models/product.rb

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
end
```

I want to make a company edit form with checkboxes for products and also have an option to add new products.

[image]

Six products listed above are default products for all companies.

Products added with other field will only be shown to the company who added them, like the following.

[image]

**The problem:**
I can't add other company specific products with my current HABTM association, I want to know the rails way to achieve this. Please help!

Comment: you can fetch the products using `Product.pluck(:name)`

Comment: My question is: How can I can more products for that company through Other input field after displaying default products for all companies?

Answer (score 0):

Adding dynamic fields to form with HABTM associations. I found this article helpful. [http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1][1]

Hope your looking for the same